# How do I delete all child directories not pointed at by a symlink?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I’m using bash shell on Ubuntu 16.04.  I have a symlink set up like so

```
$ ls -al /home/myuser/web/current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser 40 Feb 25 15:49 /home/myuser/web/current -> /path/to/main/releases20220225152608
```

The “releases” directory contains several other directories

```
$ ls /path/to/main/releases
20220223111602
20220224122838
20220225152608
```

How would I delete all other child directories in “/path/to/main/releases“ that are not pointed at by the symlink, “/home/myuser/web/current”?

Comment: `k=$(realpath /home/myuser/web/current); for d in "${k%/*}"/*; do [[ $d = $k ]] || rmdir "$d"; done` ?

Comment: running this results in a "[[: not found" error and also it appears the script is trying to remove waht is pointed to by the symlink.  That's the one thing I woudl like to not be removed.

Comment: Then you aren't using bash (or invoking it in POSIX mode). `[[` is a bash command. `a||b` runs `b` if `a` fails: `[[ a = b ]] || echo no match`

Comment: Anyway, probably safer to use `[ "$d" = "$k" ]` to avoid `[[`'s pattern matching on `$k`. Also then works with POSIX.

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right, I wasn't using bash.  When I use bash that error goes away however still it appears the command is attempting to delete the item pointed to by the symlink as opposed to everythign else (I say "appears" because I replaced "rmdir" with "echo" just in case things went wrong)

Comment: `set -x` and you can watch what is happening. However, I expect you inadvertently changed the command I gave. Perhaps you put `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for dir in /path/to/main/releases/*/; do
    [[ $dir -ef /home/myuser/web/current ]] || echo rm -r -- "$dir"
done
```

- The `[[ $path1 -ef $path2 ]]` test checks if the two paths refer to the same item (file, directory, fifo, ...) on disk, regardless of what links (hard or soft) are traversed in either path.
- Remove the `echo` if you are happy that the resulting code will do what you want.